# How to know the target devices of my Android App?

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app. How can I know the target Android versions that the devices should have for the app to work fine?

Please check build.grade:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "34"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.Learn"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 34
}
```

I have searched online but could not find information of which SDK version goes with which Android version of the phone.

Comment: Do you mean by Android 14, Android 13?

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine Yes I mean if I built an app and deploy it to Android devices. Which versions of Android do the devices need to have in order to run the app!

Comment: You can refer to this link https://apilevels.com/ .